# wpf Load page into the <grid> on button click

Tags: c#, wpf, grid

i have this code but i want to load frame from xaml.cs because changeing combobox item i want to load different pages. i know how to load page on grid but if i make this i cant change pages whenever combobox item changed

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="822.702" Width="805.597">
<StackPanel >
<Grid>
 //there is some text labels
</Grid>
    <Grid heigt="150" margin="0,450,0,0">
        <Frame Source="page1.xaml"></Frame>
    </Grid>



</StackPanel>
```

if i make this page1 will be loaded on grid but
if i give some name like GRD1

```
 <Grid heigt="150" margin="0,450,0,0" x:name="GRD1">

    </Grid>
```

and if I want to define the frame source in xaml.cs using c# how can I define this function

```
 <Frame Source="page1.xaml"></Frame>
```

I know that I ask a particular question but I need that the pages in grid can be variable every time combobox changes value. thank !!!!

Answer (score 1):

i find the best way for load

```
<Grid>
<Frame x:name="load_frame"/>
</Grid>
```

this is what to do on xaml
and then on button click or combobox value change  or what you want you can load any page like this

```
 private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        load_frame.Content = new ANYPAGEYOUWANT();
    }
```

I am writing this answer because I have seen that many people are trying to load page manually
thank you Jonathan Perennes

PS. I Forgot if you don't want to show navigatebar you must add

```
 <Frame x:Name="load_frame" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want display specific view based on some criteria (selected item of a combobox for your case), i recommand you to use [ContentControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol(v=vs.110).aspx) and [DataTemplateSelector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector(v=vs.110).aspx)

Edit : Pseudo code

In your window ressource create datatemplate based on the different views you want to display :

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="page1View">
        <Views:page1/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="page2View">
        <Views:page2/>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Then create a datatemplate selector that derivate from the datatemplate selector class : [Exemple of implementation](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Using-Data-Template-f6dc23c8)
In the datatemplate selector's SelectTemplate method you can return the good datatemplate either by using "FindResource" methods or by creating datatemplate properties in your datatemplateselector class and link them to your datatemplate declared in the xaml

Than add it in your window ressources :

```
    <local:MyDataTemplateSelector x:Key="MyDataTemplateSelector" />
```

Then use a contentcontrol that will display the right view based on your combobox selected item by using the template selector

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding ComboboxSelectedItem}" ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource MyDataTemplateSelector }"/>
```

Comment: can you show me ho to do. if i use datacontet it ask me to fill all window not grid

Comment: I edited my post with some pseudo-code for your understanding